# Converting SVG xml to a vector-based symbol as the icon for a Google map marker

Tags: javascript, json, xml, dictionary, svg

I am trying to add a svg image as a custom marker icon on google Maps. I am facing some trouble trying to make it work on IE-11

So I decided to use SVG path notation as described here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-symbol-custom

```
var goldStar = {
path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
fillColor: 'yellow',
fillOpacity: 0.8,
scale: 1,
strokeColor: 'gold',
strokeWeight: 14
};

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: map.getCenter(),
icon: goldStar,
map: map
});
}
```

I've tested it on IE-11 and it works fine.

So now my problem is that I have to write a similar object notation for my custom svg i.e

converting a xml based nested tag syntax

like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="23px" height="46px">
<g>
<path fill="#237464" d="something"/>
   <g>
  <g>
     <path fill="#347256" d="something-else"/>
  </g>
  <path fill="#dda" d="something-else-altogether"/>
```

and so on./..... some more nested path elements inside g's

and I have to convert this form to an object form like the one defined for Goldstar vector image defined above.

```
var goldStar = {
path: 'M 125,5 155,90 245,90 175,145 200,230 125,180 50,230 75,145 5,90 95,90 z',
fillColor: 'yellow',
fillOpacity: 0.8,
scale: 1,
strokeColor: 'gold',
strokeWeight: 14
};
```

Is there any online-tool/documentation/rules to convert this xml like svg construct to a JSON notation? I'm really stuck on this.
Please help